# How to use split with utf8 coding?

Tags: python

I use builtin split function and i have a problem:

```
>>> data = "test, ąśżźć, test2"
>>> splitted_data = data.split(",")
>>> print splitted_data
['test', ' \xc4\x85\xc5\x9b\xc5\xbc\xc5\xba\xc4\x87', ' test2']
```

Why this is happen? What should I do to prevent this?

Python 2.7.1

Comment: what did you expect? try `print splitted_data[1]` you are looking at the internal representation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's purely the output you get from `str.__repr__` (calling `repr()` on a string). The `\xc4` etc. is just the actual way it's stored. When you print it it's still the same:

```
>>> data = "test, ąśżźć, test2"
>>> data
'test, \xc4\x85\xc5\x9b\xc5\xbc\xc5\xba\xc4\x87, test2'
>>> print data
test, ąśżźć, test2
```

`list.__str__` and `list.__repr__` use the representation of the string, but if you access the item inside it, it's still correct:

```
>>> splitted_data = data.split(",")
>>> splitted_data
['test', ' \xc4\x85\xc5\x9b\xc5\xbc\xc5\xba\xc4\x87', ' test2']
>>> print splitted_data[1]
 ąśżźć
```

Answer (score 3):

While your snippet works (escapes are just how `repr` works), you shouldn't treat bytestrings as text. Decode first, operate later.

```
data       = u"test, ąśżźć, test2" # or "test, ąśżźć, test2".decode('utf-8')
split_data = data.split(u",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the internal representation of `splitted_data`

```
data = "test, åäö, test2"
data
'test, \xe5\xe4\xf6, test2'

data.split()[1]
'\xe5\xe4\xf6,'

print data.split()[1]
åäö,
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by everyone else, there is nothing wrong with your procedure. Your expectations are not met because the presentation of a printed list chosen by Python is not the list of the contained strings. Compare with the following:

```
>>> data = "test, ąśżźć, test2"
>>> a,b,c = data.split(",")
>>> print a,b,c

test  ąśżźć  test2
```